# Problem with the implementation of DFS recursively

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search

I have tried to implement DFS on my own recursively, but i have a problem. I can't find where my mistake is. I tried to implement it entirely on my own and I am having a problem. Most implementations of DFS I have seen use OOP and I am trying to implement it simply by list of neighbours with dynamic array.

```
using namespace std;

void DFS(vector<int> *numNodes, int startingVertex, bool* used) {
for(int i:numNodes[startingVertex]) {
    if(!used[i]) {
        used[i] = true;
        cout<<i<<endl;
        DFS(numNodes, i, used);
    }

}
}

int main()
{
int n, k, temp, startingVertex;
cin>>n;
vector<int> numNodes[n];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    cout<<"How many neighbours for node "<<i<<"?"<<endl;
    cin>>k;
    cout<<"Enter neighbours"<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<k; j++) {
        cin>>temp;
        numNodes[i].push_back(temp);
    }
}
cout<<"Enter starting point"<<endl;
bool used[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    used[i] = false;
}

cin>>startingVertex;
cout<<"Starting DFS from vertex "<<startingVertex<<"..."<<endl;
cout<<startingVertex<<endl;
used[startingVertex] = true;

DFS(numNodes, startingVertex, used);
}
```

Comment: What *is* your problem? Do you get build errors? Does it crash when running? Get wrong results? What? Please take some time to refresh about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: OT: `bool used[n];` is a [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which is optional since C99 but not standardized in C++. (If it compiles it does due to a compiler extension.)

Comment: Try to never ever use pointers as function argument directly in C++. Use std::uniq_ptr, std::shared_ptr and references. And replace the bool used[n] with std::vector for the reason Scheff mentioned. And use const wherever possible. numNodes should be const, right?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of comments on the ticket about good C++/coding practices, but from an algorithmic standpoint, the issue I'm seeing is that after the recursive call of `DFS(numNodes, i, used);` you need to set `used[i]` back to `false`, so that node `i` can be used again for another path through the graph.